# How can I increment an infix variable in Bash?

Tags: bash, awk, pipe

I have a string `foo-0` that I want to convert to `bar1baz`, i.e., parse the trailing index and add a prefix/suffix. The part before the trailing index (in this case `foo-` can also contain numeric characters, but those should not be changed.

I tried the following:

```sh
echo foo-0 | cut -d'-' -f 2 | sed 's/.*/bar&baz/'
```

but that gives me only a partial solution (`bar0baz`). How can I increment the infix variable?

**EDIT**: the solutions below only work partially for what I am trying to achieve. This is my fault because I simplified the example above too much for the sake of clarity.

The final goal is to set an environmental variable (let's call it `MY_ENV`) to the output value using bash with the following syntax:

```sh
/bin/sh -c "echo $var | ... (some bash magic to replace the trailing index) | ... (some bash magic to set MY_ENV=the output of the pipe)"
```

Side note: The reason I am using `/bin/sh -c "..."` is because I want to use the command in a Kubernetes YAML.

**Partial solution (using `awk`)**

This works:

```sh
echo foo-0 | awk -F- '{print "bar" $2+1 "baz"}'
```

This doesn't (output is `1baz`):

```sh
/bin/sh -c "echo foo-0 | awk -F- '{print \"bar\" $2+1 \"baz\"}'
```

**Partial solution (using arithmetic context and parameter expansion)**

```sh
$ var=foo-0
$ echo "bar$((${var//[![:digit:]]}+1))baz"
```

This does not work if `var` contains other numeric characters before the trailing index (e.g. for `var foo=r2a-foo-0`.

Comment: If you set the environment variable in a subshell, it won't affect the parent environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `awk`:

```
awk -F- '{print "bar" $2+1 "baz"}' <<< 'foo-0'
```

```
bar1baz
```

Comment: This does not work when using `/bin/sh -c "echo 'foo-1' | awk -F- '{print \"bar\" $2+1 \"baz\"}'"` (output is `1baz`). I updated the question with more details about what I need the solution for.

Comment: You will need to use: `/bin/sh -c "echo 'foo-1' | awk -F- '{print \"bar\" \$2+1 \"baz\"}'"` with escaped `$` to avoid variable expansion in calling shell.

Comment: I marked this answer as correct since it provides the easiest solution for the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an arithmetic context and parameter expansion:

```
$ var=foo-0
$ echo "bar$((${var//[![:digit:]]}+1))baz"
bar1baz
```

Unrolled, from the inside:

- `${var//[![:digit:]]}` removes all non-digits from `var`:

  ```
  $ echo "${var//[![:digit:]]}"
  0
  ```
- `$((blah+1))` adds 1 to the variable `blah`:

  ```
  $ blah=0
  $ echo "$((blah+1))"
  1
  ```

  or, instead of `blah`, we can use the result of the inner substitution:

  ```
  $ echo "$(( ${var//[![:digit:]]} + 1 ))"
  1
  ```
- and finally, putting this between `bar` and `baz`, you get `bar1baz`.

---

Amending for the other case brought up: assuming there might be other digits and we want to increment only the trailing ones, e.g.,

```
var=2a-foo-21
```

To do this, we can use nested parameter expansion with extended globs (`shopt -s extglob`) and the `+(pattern)` pattern, which matches one or more of *`pattern`*. Observe:

```
$ echo "${var#"${var%%+([[:digit:]])}"}"
21
```

The outer expansion is `${var#pattern}`, which removes the shortest match of *`pattern`* from the beginning of `$var`. For *`pattern`*, we use

```
"${var%%+([[:digit:]])}"
```

which is "remove the longest match of `+([[:digit:]])` (one or more digits) from the end of `$var`". This leaves us with just the trailing digits, and incrementing them and adding string before and after looks something like this:

```
$ echo "bar$((${var#"${var%%+([[:digit:]])}"}+1))baz"
bar22baz
```

This is so unreadable that I'd suggest using regex instead:

```
$ re='([[:digit:]]+)$'
$ [[ $var =~ $re ]]
$ echo "bar$((${BASH_REMATCH[1]}+1))baz"
bar22baz
```

Comment: This does not work when `var` contains other numeric characters before the trailing index (e.g. `r2a-foo-0`). This is a prerequisite. I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: @tiefenauer I've added another solution that takes this into account. Notice that it's generally frowned upon to amend a question such that it invalidates existing answers.